# Bootstrap multiple modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you help me out solve this modal with bootstrap I really don't have a clue

[image]

a multiple modal in one window

Comment: I think you need to make your question more concrete. Or actually pose a question.
I think this is just one modal with tabs inside.

Comment: @sniels thank you :) that what I needed please, post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, it seems that it is just one modal.
Within the modal there's multiple tabs, but they don't open a new modal, just show different content.